# Background Image won't show on IE 8

Tags: html, css

The background image in class 'Logo' won't show on IE8. After looking around in stackoverflow, I tried changed the image to PNG format. It still won't show.

Here is the basic structure of my divs.

```
<header>
     <div class="headcontain">
          <div class="logo">
                <div class="nav2"></div>
                <div class="fbmainlike"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
</header>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.header {
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #666;
}
.headcontain {
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    width: 1043px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 50px;
}
.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(image/logo2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 130px 49px;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
}
.nav2 {
    height: inherit;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    float: left;
}
.fbmainlike {
    padding-top: 12px;
    width: 450px;
    float: right;
    color:#FFF
}
```

The background image is visible onFirefox and Chrome seem to be fine.

Comment: `.header` should just be `header` as it's not a class. Also I'm sure `header` wont work in IE8 as HTML5 isn't supported properly I think

Comment: Your `Css` is case sensitive. Change the class from `.logo` to `.Logo` (uppercase)

Comment: "<header>" tag will only support in IE9+,Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: Sorry for the case confusion in the post. Edited

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be mixing uppercase and lowercase in selectors.

You have:

```
 <div class="headcontain">
      <div class="Logo">
```

But in CSS:

```
 .Headcontain {...
```

and

```
 .logo {...
```

CSS selectors are case-sensitive. Try unifying the selectors in CSS and HTML.

Comment: yep, just as @Leszek has pointed out, its just the case mismatch. This will show up in IE

Comment: Sorry for the case confusion in the post. Edited

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: hidden; height: 1%;` to your `.logo`

Try this:

```
.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('image/logo2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 130px 49px;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1%;
}
```

## url without inside quote ' ' might be a problem

Comment: Can you explain? What would this change?

Comment: This would shows the background in IE. This is the hack for ie.

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(image/logo2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 130px 49px;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
}
```

Do the background-image **conflicts** with background-image ?

> because of the rules in hierarchy of css